# Manwha/manga where the main female character can see the future

Tags: story-identification, manga

All I remember is that the female protagonist knows the future and goes on a carriage ride and finds the male lead and saves him from losing an eye because of his magic/mana. Right after that, soldiers stop their carriage and she hides him under her skirt while she smokes a pipe (for health reasons).

At one point she asks him to destroy a magic tunnel or portal.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-manga-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Answer (score 5):

This is most likely [A match made in mana](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/a-match-made-in-mana) (also known as Lilien of Turin).

The protagonist knows the future because she took over the character in a book (how is not really explained). When she took over the body the mana in her body became damaged and to combat the symptoms she is gifted a pipe that can vaporize herbs by her older brother.
All the other story points you remember happen as well, the male lead has too much mana, to the point it harms him.

Comment: You’re the best seriously, thank you

Comment: @Dhenny If you're the same person as Jenn who asked the question, then please [merge your accounts](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) so that you can mark this answer as correct (using the checkmark on the left that appears only to the user who asked the question originally).