# Manhwa where female lead has to touch male lead

Tags: story-identification, manga, reincarnation

A while back I began reading a manhwa that I do not remember well but I do believe it took place in a fantasy historical setting and the male lead had dark hair and the female lead had lighter hair and she was some type of guide who would touch him so that the build up of mana he had didn't drive him crazy so she was paid to stay beside the male lead who was a nobleman.

I distinctly remember that there were other characters that also wanted her guiding which I believe was a man with darker skin and a priest or pope who was quite antagonistic with white hair.

I do also think she had two younger siblings who were said to later develop abilities but I am not completely sure because I was reading several things at the time.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?

Comment: Hair colors are reversed, but perhaps [Match made in mana](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/275344)? It has the mana theme but I haven't  read it so I don't know if the other details match up (hence comment and not an answer)

Comment: I have read Match made in Mana but it isn't that one the relationship was nof symbiotic it was a guideverse type of manhwa even though I don't remember if that was stated explicitly in the plot.

Comment: "guideverse" is something I've never heard of before. There's a tag for it on mangaupdates - are you certain it was a story like this, or that the protagonist was a women? Because every result I'm getting is shounen ai.

Comment: It has the basic concept of guideverse even if it wasn't labeled as such the female lead would touch the male lead to take energy in some way so he doesn't end up having excessive energy in his body

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may be *[Please Don't Eat Me!](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/please-dont-eat-me)*. It is licensed by [Tapas](https://tapas.io/series/please-dont-eat-me-comic/info).

> Ertha Arlez is an **impoverished purifier looking to provide for her family**. Duke Zahid El Callenor is a wealthy and powerful magician looking to cleanse his evil energy. The two seem like a perfect match… except that Zahid is fated to eat Ertha alive! Ertha must keep the duke at arm’s length for her own protection, but the **intimate purification process** combined with Zahid’s nonstop flirting make that nearly impossible. Can she stave him off and stay alive, or will she be consumed by passion?

The female lead reincarnated in the world of a novel she read part of, so she's aware of many future events - making her something like a guide. She has a purification power that works on magicians such as the male lead, and can help him by touching him. She is paid to be with him, to cancel out a massive debt, although he ends up proposing to her as well.

There is reference to others potentially desiring her powers:

[image: Others want the purifier]

Hair colors are a match. I can't confirm any of the specific people that desire her, but there was mention of the church, so the priest/pope seems likely.

And she has two younger siblings, and at least one of them will awaken to powers in the future:

[image: Younger siblings] [image: Will gain powers in the future]

Found by checking the anime-planet recommendations for *A Match Made in Mana*.

Comment: For anyone wondering, yes, the "eat me" in the title is literal. It's not shown, just alluded to.

Comment: Wow yes it was this one thank you so much!